# Bench PSU leaking voltage to case and not working properly

Tags: power-supply, ground, grounding, leakage-current, fault

Tl;dr at bottom

Recently I found old bench power supply in my closet and tried to test it but display kept on displaying 0.00v and 0.00a - the power supply is voltage and current regulated and has two diodes - one for signaling it's voltage regulated and other for signaling current regulated state, currently only current state led is lighting 24/7 and meters display 0.00, I tried probing banana plugs with multimeter but voltage between ground and v+\v- is around 20-100 millivolts so it's basically not putting any power out

After metering voltage I checked for short between ground and either of voltage outputs - they're not shorted, however there's 120ohm resistance between v- and v+ banana plugs - but as I found later it's because v- is result of kind of voltage divider with virtual ground done by 3 resistors so I think it's all fine there

Later I disasembled case and started probing power supply while it was connected to mains power and it seems that between + and - voltage there's millivolt difference in voltage so I kept on probing reverse path until I reached transformer area which converts 230v AC into smaller voltage which was dependent on knob position on front of my PSU however voltage meter on front kept on showing 0.00 even though AC voltage near transformer kept changing as I rotated it - so then I started going again from transformer area to place where small voltage AC is rectified into DC but couldn't find failure point - seemed like diode which I think was supposed to rectify AC into DC was broken but when I probed across it's output and ground it basically returned voltage I was expecting but the voltage "magically disappeared" few mm away from that point

At that point I gave up and checked on turned off PSU for shorts between main cables and random points of PCB / case assembly and there were none - only ground is connected to chassis, others are not shorted

Few days later I plugged PSU fully assembled into another wall outlet using another cablw thinking it was something wrong with previous outlet or cable and I also connected 12v car bulb via banana plugs and turned PSU on, PSU voltage meter and current meter kept on showing 0.00 and bulb was not lighting, then I touched PSU case which is metal on top and got shocked quite well, it wasn't hard shock giving you black vision but i felt it pretty good in my fingers, and parallel to that light bulb ligthed up and meters on front of PSU started showing real values

After that I measured voltage between water pipe running on wall and PSU case - it was 220v, also measured current running through to same pipe - it was around 8-10mA, and noticed that when I started measuring current flow with meter between water pipe and PSU case PSU started working properly and displaying all values as it should, and at this point I gave up - I'm literally out of ideas

**Tl;dr & question:**

Seems like PSU in theory is grounded properly but in practice it's halfway grounded and it halfway works - displays light up and diodes signaling mode of work light up but unless I short PSU case with water pipe or ground in outlet using external cable or meter then it doesn't put any DC output - and my question is where should I look or what for to look?

Also overhead answer - I'm not certified / professional electrician, I'm more of "low voltage electronics and automation degree" guy, I did stupid thing by touching the case of that thing with bare hand but at least it was done subconsciously in one hand manner, and also that's the reason I'm here - if you think it's something I can diagnose with my knowledge then I will be grateful for answers, if you think it's out of my scope then it's fine either - I'll search for professional to fix it

Comment: Is the current limit control set to minimum (fully counterclockwise)?  that would hold the output voltage at, or very near, zero.  If you turn the current limit control up, the output voltage should rise, and be controlled by the voltage knob.

Comment: Yes I know but knobs do nothing if it's not shorted, no matter if I turn them both to their limits unless I short case with ground, it got me thinking that maybe the current limiting circuit is broken and it keeps at holding current at 0.001A value and when I short case to ground something inside shorts and PSU bypasses current limiter?

Comment: Does the PSU plug in with a grounded plug? Are plugs in your country symmetrical? With proper grounding this should have tripped the circuit breaker.

Comment: This is probably some trivial short circuit like a screw touching something it shouldn't. Whether it's repairable or not, I can't say.

Comment: cable for psu is same as for PC atx psu - 3 pin with ground, plug is EU - one ground pin and "neutral" + "hot" (thats how theyre called in my country), cables do not touch case anywhere and are soldered to psu pcb, the issue is I cannot find any short for live wires or pcb, idk if it's case of voltage "jumping" across short distance or something, but I cannot find it anywhere, my multimeter has 0.01 ohm resolution for resistance, live wires solder points to ground give infinite resistance values, thats the reason I posted it here, I'm not that profficient in electrical circuit quirks

Comment: also I thought that the issue is that I measured for short circuits while disasembled but when I put on the case it touches somewhere and shorts some points - thats also not the case because naked pcb screwed only to plastic front panel still is shorting / not making proper ground and thus making psu inoperable